# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am making a social media website from a youtuber and I am having a issue in frontend (React) part. My error is :  Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')
I have checked many times by commenting every part and the issue is in Post .Please Help

```
const Account = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { loading, error, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.myPosts);
  const { error: likeError, message } = useSelector((state) => state.like);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMyPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch({ type: "clearErrors" });
    }

    if (likeError) {
      alert.error(likeError);
      dispatch({ type: "clearErrors" });
    }
    if (message) {
      alert.success(message);
      dispatch({ type: "clearMessage" });
    }
  }, [alert, error, message, likeError, dispatch]);

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : (
    <div className="account">
      <div className="accountleft">
        {posts && posts.length > 0 ? 
          posts.map((post) => (
            <Post
            key={post._id}
            postId={post._id}
            caption={post.caption}
            postImage={post.image.url}
            likes={post.likes}
            comments={post.comments}
            ownerImage={post.owner.avatar.url}
            ownerName={post.owner.name}
            ownerId={post.owner._id}
            isAccount={true}
            isDelete={true}
            />
          ))
         : (
          <Typography variant="h6">You have not made any post</Typography>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="accountright"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

Comment: What is `post` at the time of the error?

Comment: Are you certain that `loading` going to `false` directly corresponds with data definitly being in `post`, and that each `post` definitly has an `_id` property once its ready? To discover this, add `console.log('Info:', loading, posts)` just above the return and report back the results of each time it outputs to the console. It looks likely that `loading` is either incorrectly always false, or it turns to false when `post` isnt actually ready. Alternatively one or more of the `post` data in the array is just missing the `_id` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the post object you are currently looping over being null. You need to do a check for the value being null inside your loop.

```
{
    posts && posts.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post) =>
            post ? (
                <Post
                    key={post._id}
                    postId={post._id}
                    caption={post.caption}
                    postImage={post.image.url}
                    likes={post.likes}
                    comments={post.comments}
                    ownerImage={post.owner.avatar.url}
                    ownerName={post.owner.name}
                    ownerId={post.owner._id}
                    isAccount={true}
                    isDelete={true}
                />
            ) : null
        )
    ) : (
        <Typography variant="h6">You have not made any post</Typography>
    );
}
```

edit: Unlike what others appear to be saying, this is neither an issue with the `_id` property or the posts loop as this wouldn't create the same error. It is attempting to read the `_id` property of `post` and is finding `post` to be null, not the property `_id`.

Comment: This'll probably work, but its perhaps worth the question author checking why the server is returning one or more null's inside the posts array, which would be unexpected server behaviour.

Comment: It would be worth checking if this data is being directly fetched from the server; however as this appears to be being fetched from Redux store, meaning it is also best practice to ensure the data hasn't been modified before being presented to the react component.

Comment: Yeh agreed, makes sense